# Why are commas not working as expected in a XSL nested for-each?

Tags: json, for-loop, xslt-1.0

**TL;DR - Problem:**  In a nested `for-each` I am unable to get commas to print correctly.  There are four cases which keep repeating.  There are other ways that I can think of to get the job done, but I really want to find out why this is behaving the way it is.

**Question**: Why are pipes working, but not commas and why does the last element print out by itself sometimes?

**Overview**: I am trying to get an XML document, which contains node relationships, into a JSON format so that I can do graph visualization.  There are a couple of ways to solve this problem and I chose the start by generating the list of nodes.  So, I have an XSL file which is transforming an XML document into a JSON tree structure of nodes.

Here is a snippet of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<knowledge_base
  xmlns="http://protege.stanford.edu/xml"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://protege.stanford.edu/xml http://www.enterprise-architecture.org/xml/essentialreportxml.xsd">
  <simple_instance>
    <name>Class181</name>
    <type>Business_Capability</type>
    <own_slot_value>
      <slot_reference>business_capability_level</slot_reference>
      <value value_type="string">3</value>
    </own_slot_value>
    <own_slot_value>
      <slot_reference>realised_by_business_processes</slot_reference>
      <value value_type="simple_instance">Class40041</value>
    </own_slot_value>
    <own_slot_value>
      <slot_reference>supports_business_capabilities</slot_reference>
      <value value_type="simple_instance">Class180</value>
      <value value_type="simple_instance">Class20022</value>
      <value value_type="simple_instance">Class182</value>
    </own_slot_value>
    <own_slot_value>
      <slot_reference>name</slot_reference>
      <value value_type="string">Help Desk Service</value>
    </own_slot_value>
  </simple_instance>
</knowledge_base>
```

There are multiple Business Capabilities and they can have Business capabilities as parents and others as children.  Here is the bulk of my XSL doc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://protege.stanford.edu/xml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns:pro="http://protege.stanford.edu/xml" xmlns:eas="http://www.enterprise-architecture.org/essential" xmlns:functx="http://www.functx.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ess="http://www.enterprise-architecture.org/essential/errorview">

  <xsl:template match="knowledge_base">
        <xsl:call-template name="BuildPage"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="BuildPage">
    <xsl:param name="pageLabel">Business Capability Graph</xsl:param>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title><xsl:value-of select="$pageLabel"></xsl:value-of></title>
        <script src="js/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          <xsl:text>
          function tree()
            {
            var json=</xsl:text><xsl:call-template name="getJSON" /><xsl:text>;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
            }
        </xsl:text>
        </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="tree();">
          <div id="main"></div>
        </body>
        </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="getJSON">
    <xsl:text>{ "nodes" : [</xsl:text>
    <!-- Get Business Caps -->
    <xsl:call-template name="getNodes">
      <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="/node()/simple_instance[type='Business_Capability']" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>]}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="getNodes">
    <xsl:param name="nodes" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$nodes">
      <xsl:variable name="name" select="own_slot_value[slot_reference='name']/value" />
      <xsl:variable name="id" select="current()/name" />
      <xsl:variable name="level" select="own_slot_value[slot_reference='business_capability_level']/value" />

      <xsl:text>{"name":"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$name" />
      <xsl:text>", "id":"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$id" />
      <xsl:text>", "level":"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$level" />
      <xsl:text>", "data":{</xsl:text>

      <xsl:variable name="pcCap_list" select="own_slot_value[slot_reference='supports_business_capabilities']" />

      <xsl:text>"pcCap":{</xsl:text>
      <xsl:for-each select="/node()/simple_instance[name=$pcCap_list/value]" >
          <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
              <xsl:text>"id" : "</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="name" />
              <xsl:text> - pos </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$pos" />
              <xsl:text> - count </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="count($pcCap_list/value)" />
              <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:text>}}}</xsl:text>
      <xsl:if test="position() != count($nodes)">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>

    </xsl:for-each>


  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Throughout the document, I have successfully used the `xsl:if test=position() != count()` to properly add commas (1, 2, 3), **EXCEPT** for within the inner `for-each` in the `getNodes` template.  I have tried many different variations, from using position(), count(), last(), !=, <, >, =, not(position() = count()), count()-1, count()+1, etc., along with `xsl:choose` with `xsl:when` and `xsl:otherwise` statements.  I keep seeing the same four patterns below (along with XSL syntax errors, and empty objects).

Here is what I have tried.  All were placed After the `<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>` and `</xsl:for-each>` of the inner `for-each` in the `getNodes` template.  First is the XSL input, my summary of what happened, & the related JSON output.

**Test 1:**

```
<xsl:if test="position() != count($pcCap_list/value)" >
  <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
</xsl:if>

No XSL error.  No JS error.  But only **last element** is printed.

{
"name": "Help Desk Service",
"id": "Class181",
"level": "3",
"data": {
  "pcCap": {
    "id": "Class20022 - pos 3 - count 3"
  }
}
}
```

**Test 2:**

```
<xsl:if test="position() = count($pcCap_list/value)" >
  <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
</xsl:if>

No XSL error.  JS errors = "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string report:8" && "Uncaught ReferenceError: tree is not defined report:125".  All three are printed as expected with the comma after the third element.

{
  "name": "Help Desk Service",
  "id": "Class181",
  "level": "3",
  "data": {
    "pcCap": {
      "id": "Class180 - pos 1 - count 3""id": "Class182 - pos 2 - count 3""id": "Class20022 - pos 3 - count 3",

    }
  }
}
```

**Test 3:**

```
<xsl:if test="position() &lt; count($pcCap_list/value)" >
  <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
No XSL error.  No JS error.  Again, only last item is shown.

{
"name": "Help Desk Service",
"id": "Class181",
"level": "3",
"data": {
  "pcCap": {
    "id": "Class20022 - pos 3 - count 3"
  }
}
}
```

**Test 4:**

```
<xsl:if test="position() &lt; count($pcCap_list/value)" > <!-- happens with both &lt; and != -->
  <xsl:text>| </xsl:text>
</xsl:if>

No XSL error.  JS errors = "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : report:8" && "Uncaught ReferenceError: tree is not defined report:125".  Prints out as expected, with pipes between the elements.

{
  "name": "Help Desk Service",
  "id": "Class181",
  "level": "3",
  "data": {
    "pcCap": {
      "id": "Class180 - pos 1 - count 3"|"id": "Class182 - pos 2 - count 3"|"id": "Class20022 - pos 3 - count 3"
    }
  }
}
```

So what is going on that causes pipes to work but not commas?  And why does the third element sometimes print by itself?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically the XSL transformer you are using that does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Your originally posted transform works on my XSL transformer.  I think your problem may be with the transformer itself.  I just copied and pasted your XML and XSL and got the desired output from XSLT.